# Snowflake Syntax when passing array into insert query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My code obtains the column list of a table I have created
the attributes of this table are the contextual values of a session in snowflake
such as USER,DATABASE,WAREHOUSE...ETC
Afterwards it places those attribute names into an array
I then try to call on these names in making an insert query and this is where I am struggling with the syntax

Because each value in my array is USER, DATABASE,WAREHOUSE
I am trying to call on the context functions
like CURRENT_WAREHOUSE()
Can someone please help me with the syntax

```
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        v_sqlCode = `INSERT INTO SESSION_ATTRIBUTES( arr[i] )
                        "VALUES ("CALL CURRENT_"+arr[i]+"()")';    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly use the output of a Snowflake stored procedure programmatically. If you need to use the output value, you have to collect it using the RESULT_SCAN table function. That can get a bit complex to handle, directly in code, so it's far better to place it into a helper function. See this example of one SP calling another one and using its output value. It does this by calling the SP using the `callSP` helper function. Use the entire SQL statement including the `call` command into the SQL parameter for that function. It will run the SP, grab the result from the result_scan table function and return it.

```
create or replace procedure HELLO_WORLD()
returns string
language javascript
as
$$
    return "Hello, world.";
$$;

create or replace procedure CALL_HELLO_WORLD()
returns string
language javascript
execute as caller
as
$$

return callSP(`call HELLO_WORLD()`);

// ---- Main function above, helper functions below.

function callSP(sql){
    let cmd = {sqlText: sql};
    let stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd);
    stmt.execute();
    let result_scan  = `select $1 from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));`;
    let result_cmd   = {sqlText: result_scan};
    let result_stmt  = snowflake.createStatement(result_cmd);
    let rs           = stmt.execute();
    if(rs.next()) {
        return rs.getColumnValue(1);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

$$;

call call_hello_world();
```

Comment: Hello Greg, first of all thanks for always helping me
Secondly, in my array there are no values but just strings
I am trying to mimic the 
"CALL CURRENT_DATABASE()" for example which will then get the current database and store it into my sessions table

Comment: I updated my answer. You can't directly read the output of a Snowflake stored procedure. You have to do it the way the example callSP function shows. You can cut & paste that into the bottom of your stored procedure and use it.